# No meta value from collection object

Tags: php, laravel, controller

```
class SongsCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
 public function toArray($request)
 {
 return [
        'data' => SongResource::collection($this->collection),
        'meta' => ['song_count' => $this->collection->count()],
    ]; 
 }
}
```

in the controller

```
$data = new SongsCollection(Song::all());

dd($data);
   `
```

it only display the image below, but without the meta array contain the song_count?
[image]

How to get the meta->song_count value  ?

Comment: `dd($data->toArray())`

Comment: it shows the error "Too few arguments to function App\Http\Resources\SongsCollection::toArray(), 0 passed in"

Comment: `toArray` method expects `$request` as argument. Correct way is to call `toJson`

Comment: I got mixed up with the method names, Nurlan Bolayev is right.

Answer (score 1):

[Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#concept-overview) says:

> Every resource class defines a `toArray` method which returns the array of attributes that should be converted to JSON when the resource is returned as a response from a route or controller method.

So, `dd($data)` will just dump the resource object which has the `toArray` method. If you want to get the meta field, you must call `$data->toJson()` method. If you just `return $data` in your api endpoint, laravel itself will call `toJson` method internally as stated in the above doc.

Comment: Thanks Nurlan,  That is right to use $data->toJson() to get the result, but there is no meta value. it is so wired.

"[{"id":1,"title":"Alice.","artist":"Lysanne Lang Sr.","rating":0,"album_id":3,"created_at":"2021-02-03 23:24:05","updated_at":"2021-02-03 23:24:05"},{"id":10,"title":"The jury.","artist":"Javon Crona","rating":3,"album_id":1,"created_at":"2021-02-03 23:24:05","updated_at":"2021-02-03 23:24:05"}] "

Answer (score 0):

In the blade template, the laravel gives a song collection, which can not be retrive the meta from this collection, Below is how I get the meta data:

```
$datas = json_encode($datas,true);
       //dd($data);
        $datas = json_decode($datas);
       // dd($datas);
       foreach($datas->meta as $link){
        echo $link;
}
```

Hope this helps.